# leaflet-geosearch search bar outside the map container with an input field

Tags: html, dictionary, web, leaflet

I want to move the search bar from the map to my own input field without loosing the automatic suggestions feature.

const searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
position: "topleft",
placeholder: "Enter address",
useMapBounds: false,
providers: [
L.esri.Geocoding.arcgisOnlineProvider({
apikey: apiKey,
nearby: {
lat: position.coords.latitude,
lng: position.coords.longitude
}
})
]
}).addTo(map);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Had the same problem, ended up building the field by myself. I used the hmtl <datalist> to show the top results from the response (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist). Be carefull to not generate too many requests and get blocked by the geocoding API you are using.